# ASP .NET Web API Post modelbinding issues

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am a web API newbie, trying my first POST to the API (all my GETs are fine). And no matter what I try, model binding doesn't seem to work. Routing is fine, because I see control coming to the correct method, but model object references is always null. I tried with a simple class as model (two properties, both strings), still no luck.
Any suggestions on what I am missing? I am using fiddler to post. eg: request body has

```
{"Name":"Test","Description":"Test"}
```

Tried with a = at the start, Tried method-argument-variable= at the start, no luck.
null always.

Comment: Perhaps you could post your controller action as well as the full request details from Fiddler (including all headers). I suspect you're not setting the `Content-Type` header.

Comment: @Ben Foster - YOU ARE RIGHT! I am missing Content-Type header. I had Accept header but not this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When you sending the parameter by request body , you must use the [FromBody] attribute in method body. [FromBody] denotes it binds the parameters from request to the model class.
Check whether you are using [FromBody] or by url ?

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public List<PortalUser> GetPortalUsers([FromBody]PortalUser PortalUser)
{ }
```